# Accesing Application DI Container in Configure Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac, autofac-configuration

With .net core 3 and above `ConfigureServices` method doesn't return `IServiceprovider`.
We used to configure Autofac in the `ConfigureServices` method and use it to resolve the registered proxies for our Controllers so that we could add the controllers as services:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        services.AddHttpClient();

        var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc(
                o =>
                {
                    o.Filters.Add<ModelStateValidationFilter>(1);
                    o.Filters.Add<RequestLogActionFilter>(int.MinValue);
                }).AddMvcOptions(o => o.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            
        builder.Populate(services);

        builder.RegisterModule(_module);

        builder.RegisterModule<DiagnosticsModule>();
        
        ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

        mvcBuilder.AddControllersAsServices().AddGeneratedControllerProxies(ApplicationContainer);

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
    }
```

`AddGeneratedControllerProxies` extension method looks like:

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddGeneratedControllerProxies(this IMvcBuilder builder, IContainer applicationContainer)
        => builder.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(
            m => m.FeatureProviders.Add(new ControllerProxyFeatureProvider(applicationContainer.ResolveOptional<IEnumerable<ControllerRegistration>>())));
```

Now since the DI service provider factory is configured differently in .net core 3+ and above, a new method `ConfigureContainer` is called at runtime where we register our modules and types.
I would like to resolve my controller proxies in the `ConfigureServices` method but I don't have access to the Container, is there anything I can do to achieve that?

Comment: This URL may solve your issue: https://medium.com/@jabbaar.15/autofac-with-asp-net-core-3-1-cf2c69c67e59

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't help @RoarS.

Comment: This isn't possible. You can't get the container until after it's built, which is after ConfigureServices runs. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to get access to the service provider during feature population either. That would make a good feature request.